# Can anyone explain this code for computing Levenshtein distance?

Tags: python, algorithm, levenshtein-distance

I was given this code that quickly returns whether the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between two strings is exactly 2.

```
def li(s, i):
    try:
        return s[i]
    except IndexError:
        return None
    
def f(str1, str2):
 t = [4, 4, 1, 2, 3]
 for i, str1_symb in enumerate(str1):
    p = 4
    res = []
    for j, t_val in enumerate(t):
        p = min(t_val - (str1_symb == li(str2, i + j - 2)), p, li(t, j + 1) or 4) + 1
        res.append(p)
    t = res
 return li(t, len(str2) - len(str1) + 2) == 3
```

You can test it with:

```
f("zzzzfood", "zzzzdodod")
```

for example which will return `True`

and

```
f("zzzzfood", "zzzzdodo")
```

which will return False.

The standard algorithm for computing the Levenshtein distance builds a dynamic programming table and fills in the elements from left to right, top to bottom using  the formula:

[image]

(from the wiki page linked above)

If you only want to return if the Levenshtein distance is at most 2 you can only look at cells of the dynamic programming that are at most 2 right or left from the diagonal.

The code above doesn't obviously do that and I can't work out what it is doing. Some particularly mysterious parts:

- What is the role of t = [4, 4, 1, 2, 3]?
- The li() function is taking both a string and a list in this code. It only returns None if the index `i` is greater than or equal to `len(s)`. Sometimes `i` will be negative where it will still return a letter from `s`.
- `li(t, j + 1) or 4` returns 4 if `li(t, j + 1)` is `None` but I don't know what its purpose is.
- What is the purpose/meaning of `p`?

Can anyone decipher it?

Comment: This is very bad code. Variables have terrible names, so it's difficult to understand what they are supposed to do.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Yes, although the code is at least short.  `i` is just an index into `str1` . Are there other variables you are interested in?

Comment: I believe that `t` is just a subset of that table you'd generate in the full algorithm - just the entries on the current row, going from two left of the diagonal, to two right of it.  And I suspect that that some or all of those 4's aren't actual values that would appear in the full table, it's just a sufficiently large value to guarantee a False result - put in places where if you're looking at the table at all, there's no possibility of a distance <= 2.

Comment: @jasonharper the entries in table depend on the two strings but `t` is fixed for all strings. How can that work?

Comment: No, `t` is recalculated for each row - see that `t = res` near the end?

Comment: @jasonharper oh yes.  So let's say it is initialised to "large, large, 1, 2, 3" in that case?

Comment: There are better codes to read and understand than this one... It's a classic - so shouldn't be too hard to find it.

Comment: Why bother decoding spagibberish; write a more understandable implementation.

Comment: @balmy it looked like it might be clever if I could understand it. That's all.

Comment: *"If you only want to return if the Levenshtein distance is at most 2 you can only look at cells of the dynamic programming that are at most 2 right or left from the diagonal."* Note that if you want to check whether two words `a` and `b` are at distance 2, then computing the set `d2a` of words at distance 2 from `a` and checking whether `b` is in it is pretty inefficient. It would be much more efficient to compute the two sets `d1a` and `d1b` of words at distance 1 from `a` and words at distance 1 from `b`, then see if there is a common word in the two sets.

Comment: @Stef The code doesn't compute `d2a` at all.  That's not what the dynamic programming table does.

Answer (score 7):

Alright -- so first, please don't use this code.

At a high level what its doing is what Stef said in the comments, checking the near diagonals.
The index position of `i` is iterating and the looped `j` is walking across the second string near the diagonal

Adding some prints make this a bit clearer:

```
def f(str1, str2):
    t = [4, 4, 1, 2, 3]
    for i, str1_symb in enumerate(str1):
        print()
        print(f"i={i}, str1_symb={str1_symb}")
        p = 4
        res = []
        print("res:", res)
        for j, t_val in enumerate(t):
            print()
            print(f" - j={j}, t_val={t_val}")
            p1 = t_val - (str1_symb == li(str2, i + j - 2))
            p2 = p
            p3 = li(t, j + 1) or 4
            print(f" - p1a: t_val - (str1_symb == li(str2, i + j - 2))  ==>  {t_val} - ({str1_symb} == li({str2}, {i} + {j} - 2))")
            print(f" - p1b: t_val - (str1_symb == li(str2, i + j - 2))  ==>  {t_val} - ({str1_symb} == li({str2}, {i + j - 2}))")
            print(f" - p1c: t_val - (str1_symb == li(str2, i + j - 2))  ==>  {t_val} - ({str1_symb} == {li(str2, i + j - 2)})")
            print(f" - p1d: t_val - (str1_symb == li(str2, i + j - 2))  ==>  {t_val} - {(str1_symb == li(str2, i + j - 2))}")
            print(f" - p1e: t_val - (str1_symb == li(str2, i + j - 2))  ==>  {p1}")
            print(" - ")
            print(f" - p2: {p}")
            print(f" - ")
            print(f" - p3a: li(t, j + 1) or 4 ==> li({t}, {j} + 1) or 4")
            print(f" - p3b: li(t, j + 1) or 4 ==> li({t}, {j + 1}) or 4")
            print(f" - p3c: li(t, j + 1) or 4 ==> {li(t, j + 1)} or 4")
            print(f" - p3: {li(t, j + 1) or 4}")
            print(f" - ")
            p = min(p1, p2, p3) + 1
            print(f" - p: min(p1, p2, p3) + 1 ==> min({p1}, {p2}, {p3}) + 1")
            print(f" - p: min(p1, p2, p3) + 1 ==> {min(p1, p2, p3) + 1}")
            res.append(p)
        t = res
        print(f"t = {t}")
    print()
    print(f"result: li(t, len(str2) - len(str1) + 2) == 3 ==> li({t}, {len(str2)} - {len(str1)} + 2) == 3")
    print(f"result: li(t, len(str2) - len(str1) + 2) == 3 ==> li({t}, {len(str2) - len(str1) + 2}) == 3")
    print(f"result: li(t, len(str2) - len(str1) + 2) == 3 ==> {li(t, len(str2) - len(str1) + 2)} == 3")
    print(f"result: li(t, len(str2) - len(str1) + 2) == 3 ==> {li(t, len(str2) - len(str1) + 2) == 3}")
    return li(t, len(str2) - len(str1) + 2) == 3
```

My read on `t = [4, 4, 1, 2, 3]` is that it's setting offset values, and maxing (so that we effectively disregard the -ive list index values, anything greater than 3 should produce the same results)
the negative list indices are superfluous computations, but harmless.

We can see how i & j move across the matrix:

[image: nested loop order]

Which produces the following difference matrix:

[image: diagonal computations]

Breaking the p computation `p = min(t_val - (str1_symb == li(str2, i + j - 2)), p, li(t, j + 1) or 4) + 1` into it's three parts makes it's work clearer:

```
p1 = t_val - (str1_symb == li(str2, i + j - 2))
p2 = p
p3 = li(t, j + 1) or 4
p = min(p1, p2, p3) + 1
```

We can see that this step is using `t/res` as a memory on the last computation where we lookup the previously calculated offsets and compute the new value

The last note is, it looks like everything is scaled up by `1` so that the author can use -true to indicate a difference; this is then added back to the `min` which scales a distance of `2` to a distance of `3` leading to the final equality

---

This was so hard to read I kept gaining some understanding then losing the thought, an interesting reverse engineering problem, but terrible production code.

---

As I spent a little time trying to come up with a better approach I realized I ended up heading down the same path; despite my criticisms of the readability I have to give props to the author for their efficiency. Computing and storing the algorithms else condition and carrying it down is clever and efficient.

Comment: Just noticed that I accidentally 1 indexed j in the table -- bad excel formatting, not representative of what the code is doing; I'll update soon

Comment: Thank you for this. Do you think you could add a more sane Python equivalent with the  same time complexity?

Comment: @donald honestly, no- I don't think there is a much more efficient way to handle this. We could swap returning None with returning 4 to get avoid the `or`s and perhaps also update li to return 4 if i is -ive, but this is about as efficient as I think someone will get. My criticism of it is the readability, not the approach. To that end I'd use real variable names (no reason not to) and get rid of all of the magic numbers, but that'd be about it

Comment: If you had the energy to write out a python solution that is easier to read I for one would be grateful.

Comment: I was 90% finished writing a cleaner interpretation with clean printing [was a little stuck trying to decide how to name the initial tval row] when I accidentally closed my unsaved notebook. I'll try to circle back to it unless someone beats me to it